# Point in polygon sql query

Tags: polygon, point

Below is a sample one polygon geometry type census shapefile information. Looking to pass a point via (latitude, longitude) so that I can perform a point in polygon and get the details of the polygon using a SQL script.

```
ID  1
STATEFP 25
COUNTYFP    1
TRACTCE 11200
AFFGEOID    1400000US25001011200
GEOID   25001011200
NAME    112
LSAD    CT
ALAND   13422840
AWATER  681467
geom    0xAD100000010427000000A696ADF545D64440C57
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] your question to specify what GIS and/or database software or library you are using and include the code you've written, along with any errors you have encountered.  You should know that most packages accept coordinates in {X,Y} order, so your points should be {longitude,latitude}.